# How to implement version control on Firebase?

Tags: version-control, documentation, firebase, gitlab

I'm currently using [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) as a prototyping tool to showcase a front end design for a [documentation tool](http://corilla.co/). In the process we've come to really like the real-time power of Firebase, and are exploring the potential to use it for our production instance of an open source/community version.

The first challenge is **version control**. Our [legacy project](http://pressgang-ccms.github.io/) used Hibernate/Envers in a Java stack, and we were previously looking at Gitlab as a way to move into a more "familiar" git environment.

#### This way?

Is there a way to timestamp and version control the data being saved? And thoughts on how to best recall this data without redesigning the wheel (e.g. any open source modules?)?

The real-time aspect of something like [Firepad](https://firepad.io/#1) is great for documentation, but we require the means to commit or otherwise distinctly timestamp the state or save of a document.

#### Or?

Or is it best to use Firebase only for the realtime functionality, and implement Gitlab to commit the instance to a non-realtime database. In other words abstracting the version control entirely out to a more traditional relationship to a db?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both options you offer are valid, and feasible.     In general,  I'd suggest you to use firebase **only** as your real-time stack (data sync).   And connect it to your own backend (gitlib or custom-db).

I've went that path,  and find the best solution is to integrate your own backend db with firebase on top. Depend on firebase exclusively for everything, and you'll hit walls sooner or later..
The best solution is to keep full control on your data structure, security and access models,  and use firebase where needed to keep clients in sync (online and offline).  The integration is simple.

Comment: Good points. Firebase makes it easy to claw back those elements of control when required to scale past early prototyping stages. Out of interest, what limitations have you hit relying on Firebase in production?

Comment: @ddri Limitation related with the app's logic, requiring hard to accomplish complexities  Coming from "normal" client-server state-of-mind, you'll miss: events/triggers/plugin/callbacks, granular/custom security, serious content validation, data work flows, etc..         In that specific app, custom backend with full control proves successful over time. Very thin duties (*api service, not typical client/server*),  data flow control, etc..     Because FB does data sync great,  there are **no** issues with handling multiple fragmented databases (*triangle: clients,server,fb*).  safer. faster.

Comment: In general - I think FB **shines** as online-offline data sync *and* transport tool, **not** as a backend-killer